# FWLSE0013E: Cannot invoke procedure JSONObject cannot be cast to JSONArray

Tags: javascript, json, ibm-mobilefirst

i have a clinet side fuction in my IBM Mobile first application named login
i get it from this [link](https://medium.com/@papasimons/worklight-authentication-done-right-with-angularjs-768aa933329c#.sjj6xmc3i).

```
login: function (username,password){    
            //promise
            var logindef = $q.defer();
            //tempuser
            tempUser = {username:username, password:password};
            userObj.username = username;
            checkOnline().then(function (onl){
                if (onl){ //online
                    console.log("attempting online login");
                    var parameters={
                            'username':'username',
                            'password':'password'
                        };
                    var options = {
                        parameters:parameters,  
                        adapter:"realmAuth",
                        procedure:"submitLogin"
                    };
                    ch.submitAdapterAuthentication(options,{
                        onSuccess: function(){
                            console.log("-> submitAdapterAuthentication onSuccess!");
                            //update user info, as somehow isUserAuthenticated return false without it
                            WL.Client.updateUserInfo({onSuccess: function(){    
                                //return promise
                                logindef.resolve(true);
                            }});
                        }
                    });
                } else { //offline
                    console.log("attempting offline login");
                    logindef.resolve(offlineLogin());
                }
            });
            return logindef.promise;
        },
```

i want to invoke an adapter function named `submitLogin`

```
function submitLogin(parameters){
        if (!parameters)
        return { 'isSuccessful': false, 'errorMsg' : 'parameters is ' + parameters};
        var role="";
        if (parameters.username=='admin') 
            role='admin';
        else
            role='customer';
        var input = {
                method : 'post',
                returnedContentType : 'plain',
                path : 'rest/default/V1/integration/' + role + '/token'+
                            '?username='+parameters.username+
                            '&password='+parameters.password,
                headers: {"Accept":"application\/json"} 
            };
            var response = WL.Server.invokeHttp(input);
            var token=response.text;
            token = token.replace("\"", "");            //delete the ""
            token = token.replace("\"", "");*/
            //token exp: l9ea4tv62mbfy7kmt0ekv6vdxmb23gjp
            if (token!=null) 
            { 
                var userIdentity = {
                        userId: parameters.username,
                        displayName: parameters.username, 
                        attributes: {
                            foo: "bar"
                        }
                };
                WL.Server.setActiveUser("AdapterAuthRealm", userIdentity); 
                
                return { 
                    authRequired: true 
                };
            }

    return onAuthRequired(null, "Invalid login credentials");
}
```

whene try to execute my application in navigator i get this error :

> [ERROR   ] FWLSE0013E: Cannot invoke procedure realmAuth/submitLogin [project Eticket] com.ibm.json.java.JSONObject cannot be cast to com.ibm.json.java.JSONArray

Comment: What version of MFP are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `parameters` array is not in the correct format.

You wrote:

```
var parameters={
                'username':'username',
                'password':'password'
                };
```

Javascript adapters expect an **unnamed**, ordered list of parameters. Not a JSON object.

It should be:

```
var parameters = ['myUsername','myPassword']
```

Your adapter signature should of course be altered accordingly, from `function submitLogin(parameters)` to `function submitLogin(username,password)`.